# CiviRules prevents adding new contact

Tags: civirules

I am having problems with CiviRules preventing a contact being added to a group.

I have a contact form where people request information, and the person is added to group "web contacts". This works nicely and the request is added as a note.

I then add a CiviRule that basically says
When a contact is added to a group and the group is "web contacts" then add an activity to a contact [Me] to mail the contact of the fact.

This totally prevents people being added to the group "web contacts" at all.

> Trigger: Contact is added to Group
>
> Linked Condition: Group is Webbkontakter
>
> Linked Action: Add activity to contact    Type: Email Status: Scheduled
>   Assignee(s): Martin Skjöldebrand

"web contacts" == Webbkontakter above.

Am I having a brainfart or something? Shouldn't this work?

Comment: Martin, I can not see what you have done or why it is not working without looking at your installation. Happy to try the scenario with my local CiviRules installation if you send me some screen prints of what you have done exactly. Additional question: is there a reason for creating an activity, and not using the 'send email' action directly from CiviRules?

Comment: You find the screen shot here: http://www.tyresoschack.se/images/CiviRules.png

Also, in principle no there is no reason not using "send email" from actions other than I can't find it ...

Comment: if you are on Drupal then webform could be a workaround

Comment: Unfortunately I'm on Joomla.

Answer (score 1):

Martin, for the **send** **email** action you need the Email API extension: https://civicrm.org/extensions/e-mail-api.
Once you install that, the **send** **email** action should be available in CiviRules.

I have just added a rule to my local installation as shown in the screen print, and it works in my installation (CiviCRM 4.7.25, CiviRules 1.13). 
[image]

I have created a group Web Contacts, and when I add a contact to that group the email is send out.

So it is kind of hard to see what is wrong on your installation? Perhaps a first step is to configure the rule as I have?

Comment: This works, but it sends the message back to the contact. What I want to do is have a heads-up to someone at the recieving organisation. Adding an "Add activity to contact" action seems to lock everything. Could there be someother  action needed to see the contact added I wonder ... (Add tag adds the contact and adds a tag).

Comment: Add activity to contact should work as well, I can test that. But you are saying you should have a signal within your organisation?  Could you solve it by having the someone at the receiving end remove them from the group in combination with a dashboard of group members?

Comment: and you do have an alternative email you can use in the send email action (other than the contact email)

Comment: I can tick the box, but I am not getting a field to enter the email address into =(. And yes, your workaround should work, it's somewhat alike to add a tag to newly created contacts. But as people are logged in fairly irregularly it would be better to push a notification at them =)

Answer (score 1):

Martin, the rule in this screen print works perfectly on my installation.
[image]

Comment: adding it to the target that is. I will try with assignee too

Comment: and it works perfectly with an assignee too. So it looks like it does not work in your configuration, which makes it hard to fix. The action in itself works AFAIK

Comment: Bummer ... Well it's good that it works. Just wondering why the ... it doesn't work on my site. Are you adding the contact to a group manually or through a webform? I'm using a Civi profile to add the contact (and form content).

Comment: I am adding the contact manually. So it could well be that there is something weird going on in the profile?

Comment: Profile adds some basic fields (based on name and address) + captcha tyresoschack.se/images/profile.png and adds it to the group when the form is submitted. That's all it does. I'll do a manual add and check if it the rule does it's thing.

Comment: And yes, adding the contact manually (not through the webform) to the group adds the "Add activity" action to the correct contact - so it something when adding the contact through the profile that messes things up.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/67929/discussion-between-martin-and-erikh-civicoop).